# Modal closing on click on textbox in angular

Tags: css, angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `NgbModal`

```
<ng-template #File let-modal>
  <div class="modal-content" id="exampleModal1" style="height: max-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="row" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <h1 class="modal-title p-tb-0">Create</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form #labelForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="labelName" (keyup)="newKeyUp()" (keyup.enter)="createNew()" type="text"
            #labelName="ngModel" class="form-control style-2" required [(ngModel)]="newFolder" maxlength="20"
            placeholder="Enter the folder name" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="btn-section right">
        <button type="button" class="btn primary-btn" (click)="createNew()">
          Create
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

ts

```
 newKeyUp() {
          this.isBtn = true;
      }
   open()
   {
   this.modalService
      .open(this.Create, {
        windowClass: "createlabelmodal",
        ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title",
        backdrop: "static",
      })

      .result.then(
        (result) => { },
        (reason) => { }
      );
     }
```

the issue is when I click on textbox the modal is closing automatically